# Upgrade from 21.04 to 21.10 broke software package managers, how do I recover?

Tags: package-management, upgrade

Just after the login of the final reboot, I saw a message about a bash script failing.
I have no idea where to start to fix this, and searches for fixes have turned up nothing.
I tried the partial update offered by the software manager without success.
I tried to report all this but:

```
$ ubuntu-bug
ERROR: hook /usr/share/apport/general-hooks/ubuntu.py crashed:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 228, in _run_hook
    symb['add_info'](report, ui)
  File "/usr/share/apport/general-hooks/ubuntu.py", line 84, in add_info
apport.hookutils.attach_casper_md5check(report,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/hookutils.py", line 1018, in attach_casper_md5check
    mismatches = check['checksum_missmatch']
KeyError: 'checksum_missmatch'
```

Comment: I am unsure.  All I know is I was offered the upgrade and it broke my packages.  I also have "Software" reporting that "Not all updates can be installed.  Run a a partial upgrade, to install as many updates as possible." etc...

Comment: 22.10 is not yet supported.  Run `cat /etc/lsb-release` or `lsb_release -a` and include the info about your system and what Ubuntu you're actually using.

Comment: $ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=21.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=impish
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 21.10"

Comment: We have practically no information. Include the version information in your question: use ' edit". Report about the problems you experience. What works? What does not work? Can you see the login screen? Can you log in? Realize we are not sitting in front of your computer. Nobody except you has a clue what is going on . Moreover, this is a Q&A site for future archival. So please avoid the drama, and remove the "HELP!".

Comment: Thank you for correcting my title.  Tried apt install synaptic.  "dpkg: error processing package libffi-dev:amd64 (--configure) package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should reinstall it before attempting configuration".  Every attempt to work with packages raises errors.

Comment: Installed synaptic.  marked all upgrades (over a thousand).  Applied.  This may correct it, but I am expecting untold time to pass.  It's been much preparing and unpacking.  Perhaps others will find this useful, but it will be hours before I can report back.

Comment: It didn't work.  It has been frozen on "Unpacking libclang-cppp11..." for a couple of hours.  I am planning on killing synaptic, rebooting, and trying again.

Answer (score 0):

If your upgrade stops after reboot, try sudo apt install synaptic, mark all upgrades, and let it finish the upgrade for you.  Expect synaptic to freeze at least once, but kill it, restart it to finish.  The run Software and see that package handling works again.